# Has and belongs to many Rails API POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, api, post, has-and-belongs-to-many

Currently I have a ReactJS application communicating with a Rails 5 API.

As part of this the React application makes a single JSON POST request to `api/v1/job` to create a new job record. This request includes information for two HABTM relationships with Tools and Technologies.

`Job - has_and_belongs_to_many :technologies`

`Job - has_and_belongs_to_many :tools`

How would I update the appropriate join tables in my rails controller with the ID's related to Job, Technologies and Tools?

The request looks as follows where the numbers are IDs:

```
{
   "job" : {
     ...
     "technologies" : [ "1", "6", "9" ],
     "tools" : [ "3", "5" ],
     ...
   }
}
```

It is worth mentioning that the request is sent as an axios POST request with JSON data so there are no traditional form fields.

I can also access the params successfully in my controller like so `@technologies = params[job][technologies]`, i'm just unsure of the next step to create the record :)

Comment: I think this should work: `job << Technology.where(id: params['job']['technologies'])`, this will create the records in join table considering that you have a single `job` object already.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually ended up with the following

```
@job['technology_list'].each do |tech|
    technology = Technology.find(tech['id'])
    @new_job.technologies << technology
end
```

In this instance @new_job is the job that was just created above in the controller.